# Confusion over textbook definition of "supremum"

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

This is the definition for supremum I found in [Principles of Mathematical Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007054235X), which seems to be incorrect to me (which probably just means I'm wrong):

> Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, $E \subset S$, and $E$ is bounded above. Suppose there exists an $\alpha \in S$ with the following properties:
>
> (i) $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $E$.
>
> (ii) If $\gamma < \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $E$.
>
> Then $\alpha$ is called the *least upper bound of E* [that there is at most one such $\alpha$ is clear from (ii)] or the *supremum* of $E$.

To me, the implication of (ii) isn't clear. I understand that the supremum functions as a kind of "maximum" for irrational numbers (excuse this imprecise intuition), but I don't see how (ii) completes this definition once we've established that $\alpha$ is an upper bound. It seems like we should say instead something like this:

> (ii) If $\gamma \in E$ and $\alpha < \gamma$ then $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of $E$.

Comment: You've misunderstood what the definition is trying to say. (i) says that $\alpha$ is an upper bound. (ii) says that $\alpha$ is the *least* upper bound (aka the supremum). That is, there can be no number less than $\alpha$ which is also an upper bound. Your alternative definition doesn't work because it contradicts (i), which says that $\alpha$ is an upper bound.

Comment: In my mind, you've simply reworded my confusion. **how** does (ii) say that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound? Why does it matter that this random $\gamma$ is not an upper bound? What bearing does this have on $\alpha$ being a supremum? @CharlesHudgins

Comment: @RobbyCostales you know what is least upper bound ? First it's also one of the upper bound like $\alpha$ and secondly if you subtract any $\epsilon$ from it , it will be no more a upper bound for that set. It's least Among all upper bounds of set . ( And note that it's ALWAYS unique for a set ) so if you understand this completely then you will get your answer why $\alpha$ is lub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, this actually makes a lot of sense now. I'd word the intuition as:

> If $\alpha$ is an upper bound such that it prevents any $\gamma < \alpha$ from also being an upper bound, then $\alpha$ is the least upper bound, or supremum

Comment: That sounds about right. In other words, there is no upper bound smaller than $\alpha$.

Comment: It's worth noting that Rudin strangely breaks with tradition and mathematical terminology here. The way Rudin defines it, we should say $\alpha$ is *a* *minimal* upper bound. Mathematicians use "minimal" to refer to an element of a set than which no element is smaller. By "least" mathematicians usually mean an element of a set that is smaller than every other element. In this case "minimal" and "least" aren't different, so it doesn't matter. But that isn't always true, so it's an odd choice by Rudin.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: how does your objection apply if $E = (-\infty, 1]$? $1$ is the least upper bound of $E$?  $E$ has no minimal upper bound in your sense in that case. (Not that the set in question here is the **complement** $(1, \infty)$ of $E$, not $E$.)

Comment: If $E = (-\infty, 1]$, then the set of upper bounds is $[1, \infty)$. The "least" element and "minimal" element of $[1, \infty)$ are both $1$, so it makes sense to say that the least upper bound (supremum) of $E$ is $1$.

Comment: To clarify, if $A$ is a partially ordered set, we say $x$ is a minimal element of $A$ if there does not exist $a \in A$ such that $a < x$. We say that $x$ is a least element of $A$ if $x \leq a$ for all $a \in A$. For real numbers, "least" and "minimal" will always be the same. There are cases where they are different, however. Rudin's definition conforms to the definition of a minimal element, but the supremum is more traditionally called the *least* upper bound, so Rudin's definition is a bit odd (though, importantly, equivalent to a more conventional definition).

Comment: To clarify a bit further, the more conventional definition I'm talking about would replace (ii) with: If $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $E$, then $\alpha \leq \gamma$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: your "clarification" disagrees with standard usage: a minimal element of $A$ is expected to belong to $A$.

Comment: @RobArthan I might not have been clear. I'm saying that $1$ is a minimal element of $[1, \infty)$, the set of *upper bounds* of $E$, not $E$ itself. The least upper bound is the least element of the set of upper bounds. All I'm saying is that Rudin has written the definition as though the least upper bound is a minimal element of the set of upper bounds, which is odd, but not a problem in the reals where the two notions are equivalent.

Comment: I think Rudin has defined "ordered set" to mean "linearly ordered set". Does that address your complaint?

Comment: Yes, Rudin is only using linear orders, so the distinction between "minimal" and "least" is irrelevant. But it's still odd that he would use the phrasing of the definition of "minimal" to describe a "least" element. It doesn't really matter though. Just something I thought was worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Supremum and maximum of a set are two sometimes different things. If a set S is bounded and closed, such that $\exists \alpha \in$S and $\alpha \geq s \forall s \in S$, then the maximum and supremum of the set S are the same, $\alpha$. However, when the set is bounded, but not closed (for example, all irrational numbers between zero and two), there is an upper bound but not a maximum within the set. In that case, to prove a number $\alpha$ is the supremum of S, you need to prove that $\alpha \geq s \forall s \in S$, and more critically that if you take any other upper bound on S $\gamma$, $\alpha \lt \gamma$.

Lets say by way of contradiction ii is false, that there is some arbitrary $\gamma$ such that $\gamma \leq \alpha$. All this would mean is that by definition, this particular value of $\gamma$ is actually the supremum of S, not $\alpha$.